# Why Would $_POST variables have trouble saving to $_SESSION in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, session, post, session-state

I'm having a really weird issue saving form values submitted through $_POST as session variables.

OK, so I have a form on page 1 which submits to page 2.

On page 2 I am setting all of the Post variables to Session variables.

On page 3 I am retrieving those variables.

On page 2 if I write something like this:

```
$_SESSION['fname'] = 'john';
```

It works fine. I can retrieve it on page 3.

If I write something like

```
$_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
```

That session variable is blank on page 3.

Even weirder, if I do something like:

```
$_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'].' Doe';
```

On page 3 I see just Doe.

Session variables that were previously set by other pages are also fine on page 3.

I have verified that the post variables are set on page 2, and I'm at a loss at this point. I'm not a PHP session expert or anything, but I have worked with them before and haven't seen anything like this.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Edit: The variable is being set in the session, it's just blank on page 3.

Comment: I would venture a guess that you "verified" the post variables incorrectly, and that they're misspelled or something to that effect.

Comment: Additionally I just verified that the session.save_path, session.cookie_path, session.name, and session_id() are the same across all 3 pages so there isn't any crazy multiple session issue going on that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

that means that something in the post (`$_POST['name']`) is not set;

try `var_dump($_POST);` on page 2 too see what actually got posted

Comment: `array(1) { ["fname"]=> string(3) "Dan" }`

Comment: @Dan there is ur answer. switch to `$_POST['fname']` and you should be good ^_^

Comment: @Dan  then select the best answer for your question. if u do that more people would be more likeley tp phelp you out on future questions :-)

Comment: Sorry Neal, I was generalizing in my first post. I have about 60 variables, name was just an example. I am using fname for that particular variable when setting the session variable. I apologize, I should have used actual code in my original question.

Comment: @Dan yes, yes you should use real code or else people would be debugging something that might not help at all ^_^

Comment: @Dan and the page that prints `array(1) { ["fname"]=> string(3) "Dan" }` is the same page you are saving it to the session?  I assume you didn't forget to call session_start()...

Comment: Correct. The session variable actually gets set. For instance on page 3 if I print_r($_SESSION); I see the fname variable, there just isn't anything set to it. The problem seems to be with the POST variable, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. Weirdest error I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

I can't resist asking: have you checked that `method="POST"` and not `GET` on the page 1 form?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the issue is because the POST data is not available when the SESSION data is written.

You can probably fix it by opening your php.ini and making sure that POST is registered before SESSION, this way, POST is available when you try to write SESSION data.

Comment: The superglobals are populated before your script gains control. The session is written out when the script ends, or you call `session_write_close()`. You don't have to 'register' POST. It's always there, and if the script was invoked via  POST call, will have the POST's key/value pairs in it.